# What does $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times A_n$ mean?

Tags: group-theory, notation

I know $A_n$ is the alternating group and that

$$\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} = \{0+2n\} \cup\{1+2n\} \quad n\in\mathbb{Z}$$

But I don't understand what the $\times$ operation signifies in this case?!

Comment: that usually means direct product

Comment: It means the product of the two groups, which admits a group structure too. Check
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product_of_groups

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elements of the direct product $G \times H$ of two groups $G$, $H$ are pairs $(g,h)$ where $g \in G$ and $h \in H$. The group operation is done componentwise:

$$(g,h)\cdot(g',h') = (g \cdot_G g', h \cdot_H h'),$$

where $\cdot_G$ and $\cdot_H$ denote the group operations in $G$ and $H$ respectively.

To be very concrete, here is a sample computation in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times A_3$:

$$(0,(1 2 3)) \cdot (1,(123)) = (0 + 1, (123)(123)) = (1, (132)).$$